# Sufficient conditions for all eigenvalues simple in stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, stochastic-matrices

The "largest" eigenvalue $1$ of a stochastic matrix is well-characterized by the classical [Perron-Frobenius theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) In particular, it gives sufficient conditions for the eigenvalue $1$ to be simple.

Are there any sufficient conditions known when all (or at least all real) eigenvalues of such a matrix are simple?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Similar problems in continuous variable (that is, for stochastic kernels rather than stochastic matrices) are considered to be difficult, so I doubt there are general methods to show simplicity of eigenvalues. The only thing that comes to my mind is a result for strictly *totally positive* matrices; see Section 6 [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379587903132).

Comment: If the matrix is irreducible, then not only the eigenvalue $1$, but all eigenvalus of modulus $1$ are simple. For the eigenvalues of smaller modulus I second @MateuszKwaśnicki's comment that the question is likely to be very difficult to answer.

Comment: Also: why do you need to prove that all eigenvalues are simple? Probably it's worth asking yourself if the result that you need holds also for matrices with non-simple eigenvalues...

Comment: @Randomguy: Just as for matrices: one requires that the arguments are arranged in an increasing order; in your example, $x_1 < x_2$. I do not think total positivity has been applied to study simplicity of eigenvalues in continuous case. Actually, when I wrote my first comment, I figured out that one should perhaps try this approach. Unfortunately, I believe that most interesting kernels are not totally positive.